# Twitter embed - How to override CSS

Tags: javascript, css, twitter, embed

I'm trying to override an embedded tweet CSS. I first tried using regular CSS but it's not understood by the tweets and doesn't seem to work : https://dev.twitter.com/web/overview/css

I'm now trying a javascript approach, but I can't manage to target the elements inside the tweet. I've been looking for answers but they are all about twitter timelines, not single embedded tweets.

I'm using https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events :

```
twttr.ready( function(twttr){

twttr.events.bind('rendered',function (event) {

var tgt = event.target;  // Now inside each tweet
// Code to target the content in order to change its css
});
```

Thank you for your help.

EDIT // Here is the working script :

```
twttr.ready( function(twttr){

twttr.events.bind('rendered',function (event) { 

    var tgt = event.target;

    $(tgt).contents().find(".EmbeddedTweet").css({  
        "border":"2px solid black",
        "border-radius":"7px",
        "max-width":"100%"
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: This may help https://dev.twitter.com/web/embedded-tweets/css or https://ctrlq.org/code/19933-embed-tweet-with-javascript

Comment: No, my CSS code isn't taken into account by the embedded tweets, this is why I tried with javascript. I am not loading the tweets using javascript, I have put the embed code in my blog's articles. Also, I want to style them entirely, not just choose the dark / light style.

Comment: If you can get RSS feed for your tweets you can do it, otherwise I doubt it’s possible..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer, here is how to style dynamically the loaded tweets :

```
twttr.ready( function(twttr){

twttr.events.bind('rendered',function (event) { 

var tgt = event.target;

$(tgt).contents().find(".EmbeddedTweet").css({  
    "border":"2px solid black",
    "border-radius":"7px",
    "max-width":"100%"
   });

 });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following codes worked for me -

```
twttr.ready(function(twttr) {
  twttr.events.bind("rendered", function(event) {
    var tgt = event.target;
    $(tgt.shadowRoot)
      .find(".EmbeddedTweet")
      .css({
        "max-width": "100%"
      });
  });
});
```